# Predict Where UI Will Land Based on Velocity (scrollrect unity)

Tags: loops, user-interface, unity-game-engine, expression, game-physics

I know this may not be a normal question but I think you can help me figure it out.

Background: I want to create a scrollrect (a scrollable UI element) that snaps onto the elements it's scrolling. So that it always comes to a stop with an element in the center. The scrolling of these scroll rects is based on the velocity your finger was swiping at when it left the screen, and if you input a certain velocity it always moves the same amount (within 1 pixel).

So I figured the smoothest way to create this snapping scroll rect would be to predict where the scroll rect would land & then adjust the deceleration rate so that it landed on the nearest element instead.

So basically I would like to:

1. Turn this loop into a math function where I can input velocity & get out the movement delta.
2. Be able to figure out what the deceleration rate should be based on the end movement delta & velocity.

Here's the code that the scroll rect uses for its movement:

```
protected virtual void LateUpdate()
{
     //It's probably easiest if you imagine positionX always starting at 0
     //but I'm no expert

     m_VelocityX *= Mathf.Pow(m_DecelerationRate, Time.unscaledDeltaTime);
     if (Mathf.Abs(m_VelocityX) < 1)
     {
         m_VelocityX = 0;
     }
     positionX += m_VelocityX * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
}
```

Where LateUpdate is called every frame, and positionX is the x position of the UI I am moving. (it holds the UI elements I want to snap too)

[ScrollRect Code](https://github.com/tenpn/unity3d-ui/blob/master/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/ScrollRect.cs)

[LateUpdate Info](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html)

[Mathf Info](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.html%22Mathf%22)

[Time.unscaledDeltaTime Info](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledDeltaTime.html)

And here are some velocities and movement deltas (how far it traveled), where the deceleration rate is 0.135 if that's helpful:

Velocity 500 -> 490

Velocity 350 -> 343

Velocity 200 -> 195

Velocity -200 -> -195

Velocity -400 -> -391

Ty all so much for the help! This math is way to hard for me to wrap my head around but I think it will end up being cool!